# Work out whether custom radio component is checked or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a custom radio component in React, when I check and uncheck the values it adds items to an object and should have true or false based on whether they are checked.

At the moment it adds the true value correctly with the name of the radio but I can't seem to find out how to work to make the option false if another option is chosen.

I am currently using

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    time_frame: {},
  }

  this.handleRadioChange = this.handleRadioChange.bind(this);
}

handleRadioChange(event) {
  let name = event.target.name
  let timeFrameCopy = this.state.time_frame;
  console.log(event.target)
  timeFrameCopy[event.target.value] = true
  this.setState({[name]: timeFrameCopy,}, this.checkState)
  return
  }
}

checkState(event) {
  console.log(this.state)
}
```

My radio component is

```js
const Radio = (props) => {
  return (
    <Col>
      <div>
        <input id={props.value} type="radio" name={props.name} value={props.value} className="visually-hidden" onChange={props.handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor={props.value} className="switch-label checkbox-label text-center">{props.label}</label>
      </div>
    </Col>
  )
}
```

export default Radio

If I check one radio button and then the other my state still has the data:

```
time_frame: {single: true, recurring: true}
```

Even though I would expect one of them to be false

Comment: Can you share the component jsx as well?

Comment: Your `handleRadioChange` has a `return` that I think you can avoid (it's actually useless) and an extra closing bracket `}`, are we missing part of the code?

Comment: If `time_frame` is a radio button property, using a bunch of bools is the wrong approach (although setting all other values to `false` is of course possible). If you use `time_frame: "single"` instead, you can easily derive whether a single Radio component is `checked` by comparing its own value to that of `time_frame`.

Comment: Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-problem-forked-j146k?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to store in the state an object called `time_frame`, which is going to contain one pair of property-value per radio input, where the name of each of them would be the property name and the `checked` status the value. If that's the case, I see a logic problem. since you're hard-coding `true` (for what I understand from your code) always instead of looking for the value stored and toggling/flipping it.

`handleRadioChange()` function should be something like:

```
handleRadioChange(event) {
        let name = event.target.name;
        this.setState((currentState)=>{
        let timeFrameCopy = currentState.time_frame;
         timeFrameCopy[name] = event.target.checked;
          return { "time_frame": timeFrameCopy };
        });
}
```